# Algorithm to acquire location id from piece number

Tags: python, algorithm

I will describe the algorithm in question with an example:

I have a piece, lets say piece number `7`.

I have a `4 x 4` sized puzzle with id's

```
00 01 02 03
10 11 12 13
20 21 22 23
30 31 32 33
```

I need to determine the correct location for piece `7`

The location would be `12`

I'm writing this in python and think I could use a bruit force method. I've tried counting up and reaching the location I need.

Any ideas for a simple algorithm? The output needs to to be the same since I'm working with legacy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REVISED

use a modulo and a division operation to find the x and y coordinates
the whole number of the piecenumber/columns is the x coord
the whole number of the piecenumber%columns is the y coord #i.e. the remainder of the piecenumber/columns

NOTE:  remember that rows and columns in python start with 0 not with 1. so the third row is actually row number 2.  the tile in coordinate 0,0 is number 1 so you subtract 1 from the y coordinate.  Therefore your algorithm is this:

```
valueyouwant=grid[tilenumber/numberofcolumns][tilenumber%numberofcolumns-1]
```

i.e. the 34th tile on a 6x7 grid=

```
34/6 =5 (ignore remainder)
34%6 =4 -1 = 3

x=5
y=3

00 01 02 03 04 05
10 11 12 13 14 15
20 21 22 23 24 25
30 31 32 33 34 35
40 41 42 43 44 45
50 51 52 53 54 55
60 61 62 63 64 65

Answer is 53
```

or for you example:

```
piecenum=7
row=piecenum/4
column=piecenum%4-1
value you want = puzzle[row][column]
```

Comment: so if we have a 5*9 and we want to place piece 11. the answer should be 20. If we want to place piece 17 the answer would be 31.

Comment: It isn't always square. And sorry I wasn't clear. Its not about placing the piece not the matrix it is about get the id of the location of the grid.

Comment: how is grid[tilenumber/columns][tilenumber%columns-1] not pythonic?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [python list comprehension](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) in purpose of [flattening a nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/699864). :)

And that's how it's done:

**data1.txt**

```
00 01 02 03
10 11 12 13
20 21 22 23
30 31 32 33
```

**data2.txt**

```
00 01 02 03 04
10 11 12 13 14
20 21 22 23 24
30 31 32 33 34
40 41 42 43 44
50 51 52 53 54
60 61 62 63 64
70 71 72 73 74
80 81 82 83 84
```

**acquire_location.py**

```
def acquire_location_id(data, piece):
    return data[piece - 1]


def read_file(filename):
    data = []

    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            data.append([str(x) for x in line.split()])

    return [x for sublist in data for x in sublist]


data = read_file('data1.txt')
print acquire_location_id(data, 7)
# 12

data = read_file('data2.txt')
print acquire_location_id(data, 11)
# 20

print acquire_location_id(data, 17)
# 31
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but its interesting nonetheless. Thanks :) +1

Answer (score 0):

About get id of `x,y` location:
`Id=y*width+x=y*4+c` in this case